# Execute Code First Migrations always unchecked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, publishing

In the Publish dialog box for my ASP.NET MVC web application, under Settings > Database connection string, the checkbox "Execute Code First Migrations (runs on application start)" is unchecked by default. When I check it and Save, then open Settings again, that checkbox is unchecked again.

What can I do to saved it as checked? My other projects don't seem to have this problem.